# Bounds on the effect of a matrix product on the Frobenius norm

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, norms

I was wondering if there was a way to put upper and lower bounds on the Frobenius norm of a matrix product in relation to the Frobenios norm of one of the individual matrices, i.e,

$c_1\|A\|_F\le\|AS\|_F\le c_2\|A\|_F$,

where $A$ has no particular structure (except full column-rank) and is tall; and $S\succeq0$, has full row-rank, and is fat. (Similar to the RIP re: Compressed Sensing.) I've calculated a simple and sufficient upper bound based on the submultiplicity inequality $\|AS\|_F\le \|A\|_F\|S\|_F$ (so $c_2=\|S\|_F$) but am having a hard time with the lower bound. However, I have proven experimentally that if the **rows** of $S$ have similar power, the bounds are tighter. This is something I am banking on and would like to incorporate it into a mathematical proof.

(An aside: I know that $AS\neq0$, [i.e., $c_1>0$] because $\text{null}(S^T)$ is empty [because $S$ is fat], but that's not of much use...)

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: One extra constraint can be placed on $S$: it is reasonable to assume that most elements are non-zero.

Comment: Well, you are underspecifying your problem, since obviously the product can be zero, unless you are more precise about your height and bulk.

Comment: What does "$S\succeq0$ and is fat" mean?

Comment: $S\succeq0$ means that all elements of $S$ are non-negative, and fat is this context means more columns that rows (looking at the matrix written down, it would look "fat"). Apologies if that wasn't clear

Comment: "$S$ is fat" does not imply $\operatorname{null}(S^T)=\{0\}$. Anyway, am I overlooking something, or you can get the missing bound working with $\sigma_{\min}(S)=||(SS^T)^{-1}||_2$? I can write more if you wish, but this seems a standard approach and maybe I am overlooking something.